# How to insert bcrypt hashed value into MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, hash, insert, bcrypt

I want add a student record to mysql database.For that I want to add the password field hashed using bcrypt. It is possible to seed to database using laravel seeder. But how it is possible to insert to database directly using mysql insert query?

Comment: you first should encrypt your password variable with bcrypt and then use that encrypted variable as a value in your insert statement